# form.as_hidden doesn't pass values to POST

Tags: python, django, forms

My form has initial values in it. I use form.as_hidden to hide the values and pass those values through a POST request. However, the hidden values are not passing through. Is there a way through this?

views.py

```
def car_detail_view(request, id):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CarForm(request.POST)
    print(form.is_valid())
    if form.is_valid():
        car_save = form.instance
        get_car = Car.objects.get(number_plate=car_save.number_plate)
        get_car.available = False
        get_car.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    car = Car.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CarForm(initial={'brand':car.brand, 'number_plate':car.number_plate, 'price':car.price,
                        'available':car.available})
    args = {
        'car':car,
        'form':form
    }
return render(request, 'map/confirmation.html', args)
```

confirmation.html

```
<h1>Confirmation of Booking</h1>
{% block content %}
<p>Brand: {{ car.brand }}</p>
<p>Number Plate: {{ car.number_plate }}</p>
<p>Price: {{ car.price }}</p>
<p> Are you sure you want to book? <p>
<form class="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_hidden }}
  <input type="submit" value="Book {{ car.brand }}">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Error

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>brand<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>number_plate<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>price<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: Easiest way to debug this is look at the HTML source in your browser. You'd see that apart from the csrf token, the html form is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have a `form.as_hidden` method. Therefore `{{ form.as_hidden }}` will render as the empty string `''` in your template.

You can use the `as_hidden` method for individual form fields.

```
{{ form.number_plate.as_hidden }}
```

If you use values from hidden fields, you might need to add code to prevent the user altering the field values (e.g. with their browser's developer tools). However, in your case you don't need to get the values from the form, you can fetch them from the database.

```
def car_detail_view(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        car = Car.objects.get(id=id)
        car.available = False
        car.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        car = Car.objects.get(id=id)
        args = {
            'car':car,
        }
        return render(request, 'map/confirmation.html', args)
```

Once you've got this working, you might want to think about what happens if two users try to book the same car at once.